# In the fundamental theorem of calculus, why does $x$ in $\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^xf(t) \hspace{1mm} dt$ have to be in the open interval $(a,b)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Suppose $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then why does the fundamental theorem of calculus state that $x$ in $\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^xf(t) \hspace{1mm} dt$ has to be in the open interval $(a,b)$?

I want a rigorous answer, as in proving the FTC (the "standard" way), we apply the definition of the derivative, the mean value theorem for integrals (which does not restrict the boundaries) and some limit properties. To me, it is not clear that using these results would restrict $x$ to the interval $(a,b)$ as opposed to just $[a,b]$. Any ideas?

Comment: If you allow one-sided derivatives at endpoints, then the result remains valid on all of $[a,b]$. The restriction onto the open interval is not fundamental, but rather of convenience.

Comment: No reason. The derivative is $f(x)$ even for $x=a$ and $x=b$  provided you are talking  about the right-hand derivative at $a$ and the  left-hand derivative at $b$

Comment: Is $f$ a continuous function from $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ or is $f$ a function from, for instance, $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which is continuous on $[a,b]$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring That difference is one reason to state the theorem this way. If $f$ is defined in $\mathbb{R}$ and is not continuous outside the closed interval, the derivative of the integral at $a$ or $b$ might not exist at all.